# Laravel 5 How to delete file which is inside resources/view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm a newbie in Laravel framework.

**Here is my purpose:-**

I stored a report file in *HTML* format inside view folder because I need to restrict access to this view.
Currently, I route and send a parameter of a blade file parsing to my controller.

**My controller delete function as follows:-**

```
public function centos7_delete($id)
{
    //
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user){
        \File::Delete('/resources/views/report/centos7/'. $id);
        echo '/resources/views/report/centos7/'. $id;
        return view('centos7dir');
    } else {
        return redirect('/permission_denied');
    }
}
```

An example filename which is routed and parsed to Controller.

```
result_target2.blade.php
```

I'm not sure, how many ways to do it on the Laravel framework? Please help me suggest or provide some guidelines.

Thank you.

Comment: The resources directory is not the place you want to be using for file storage. Its for files that will be rendered in the browser. You should read through this:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem and come back with any questions you may have.

Comment: So, is that mean it not possible to remove the file which is kept inside resource/view?

Answer (score 1):

Okay i did it like this,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

Route::get('/test',function(){
    //dd(base_path('resources/views/test.blade.php'));
    $isDelted = File::delete(base_path('resources/views/test.blade.php'));
    dd($isDelted); // returns true if deleted if not false
})->name('test');
```

One more thing i would like to add , make sure to give permission to read and write to folder.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found

Comment: When that error occur ? which url are you calling ? i've made this test in route file.

Comment: I added this line inside my controller function:-

     $isDelted = File::delete(base_path('resources/views/test.blade.php')); and changed to my path

Comment: And added this line use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; into the first line of my controller

Comment: So did it work or that's when you're getting error ? `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found` this simply means you need to use Storage; but i don't see any need of storage in my code.